# How to sort results inside XSLT tranformation?

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1PuPb

Is it possible to sort results in a `xslt` transformation before writing them to the output stream?

My goal is to 1) transform the following xml to csv, 2) to sort the persons by number of `<person>` occurances within a `<personNode>`.

Example: in the following, the last person node contains only 1 person. Therefore, I want to sort this person on top of all results in the final output.

Then, all persons that have been in nodes with 2 persons should be printed. Then 3..., then N.

source.xml:

```
<personNodes>
    <personNode>
        <person>
            <id>1</id>        
            <name>john</name>
        </person>
        <person>
            <id>11</id>        
            <name>doe</name>
        </person>
    </personNode>
    <personNode>
        <person>
            <id>2</id>        
            <name>jane</name>
        </person>
    </personNode>
</personNodes>
```

transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

    <xsl:template match="personNodes">
        <xsl:for-each select="personNode">
            <xsl:for-each select="person">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(id, ';', name, '&#10;')"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
1;john
11;doe
2;jane
```

Resired result:

```
#person from 1-person node
2;jane
#persons from 2-person nodes
1;john
11;doe
#persons from 3-person nodes
...
#persons from N-person nodes
```

Is that possible at all, because I just print the results to the output stream by `<xsl:value-of>`? Maybe I'd have to collect the csv lines inside a `map` or `list` variable, and then at the end loop again with printing to the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xsl:sort` of course:

```
<xsl:template match="personNodes">
    <xsl:for-each select="personNode">
        <xsl:sort select="count(person)"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="person">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(id, ': ', name, '&#10;')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1PuPb/1.

With support for higher-order `sort` (e.g. Saxon EE or PE) you could also use

```
<xsl:for-each select="sort(personNode, (), function($p) { count($p/person) })">
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
<xsl:for-each select="personNode/person">
    <xsl:sort select="../count(person)" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(id, ': ', name, '&#10;')"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```